# How can I stop auto-compiling .ts files when save on VSC

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

When I save a .ts file, it is automatically compiled to the same directory. I want to stop this. I just want to compile the files using the scripts I have in my package.json. I'm using VSC and this is my *tsconfig.json*.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
  },
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: do not use the `watch` npm script

Comment: The problem was that when I saved a file it creates a dist/ directory in the same directory of the file, so I had a lot of dist/ directories. Not only the dist/ in the root file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I changed the ***settings.json*** file in the ***.vsc*** directory.

```
{
  "compile-hero.disable-compile-files-on-did-save-code": true
}
```